# Passing data from one webpage to another

Tags: javascript, html

I have two HTML(H1, H2) pages one linked to another. I call a webservice and populate a drop down with the data response, in H1. After some operations, I move to H2. In H2, I need same data recieved in H1 from the webservice. recieved data is a large xml file.

Is there a way I can reuse the data from H1 without calling webservice again?

PS: H1 and H2 don't share any java script.

Comment: @JacobMattison How H2(simple html) will access the posted data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Session` to store the data in H1 and again use that data in H2.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Jquery post and ajax functions. With them you can easily achieve what you want.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `localStorage` ,`sessionStorage` or `cookies`.

Take a look at ***[localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)***.

Comment: I used $.ajax to get the XML data. But, looks like localStorage only stores String value?

Comment: @Forkmohit. Yes, you can stringify the result you get from AJAX call and save it to localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way without using jquery would be to merge the two pages into one, hide one, then display it when necessary. Simple exaple:

```js
window.showPage = function(page)
{
  document.getElementById(page).style.display = 'block';
  page = (page - 1) * -1;  // my jenky switch
  document.getElementById(page).style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<div id="0">
  <h1>Page 1</h1>
  <p>Hello, World!</p>
  <br>
  <a href="#" onclick="showPage(1)">Page 2</a>
</div>
<div id="1" style="display:none">
  <h1>Page 2</h1>
  <p>Hello, Forkmohit!</p>
  <br>
  <a href="#" onclick="showPage(0)">Page 1</a>
</div>
```